# In clone() we use super.clone() then access a variable that is not in super, how comes?

Tags: java

There is something that I don't understand in the usual implementation of the clone method.
If you look at the first line in the try block in the following code, we are calling super.clone(), which will create an instance of the of the super class, and return an Object reference to that instance. Now, that instance does not necessarily contain hireDay, so how are we saying copy.hireDay? It is true that it will compile fine, but shouldn't it crash if the instance does not contain hireDay?

```
public Object clone() {
    try {
        Employee copy = (Employee) super.clone(); // copy ID, name, and salary!
        copy.hireDay = (Date) hireDay.clone();
        return copy;
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contract of `clone` is to achieve the same calling pattern as with constructors: the first step is always to call the superclass implementation. This results in `Object.clone` being invoked first and all subclasses use the instance returned by that method.

`Object.clone` will return an instance of the same class as the one being cloned. This happens by extralinguistic magic, basically by a bitwise copy of the memory block + necessary changes to the copy.

The cloning mechanism is fragile because any noncompliant class in the ancestor chain breaks cloning for all its descendants. This is one of several reasons why this mechanism is disfavored.

Comment: Can you give us an example of a noncompliant class in the ancestor chain (preferably related to the Employee class). Also, what is a better mechanism than cloning?

Comment: Any class that doesn't return the instance obtained from `super.clone()` is noncompliant.

Comment: Ok, so we always need to call super.clone(). Is there a better mechanism than cloning?

Comment: Yes, there are other standard idioms, like copy constructors or serializing-deserializing in memory.

Answer (score 3):

`clone()` is a special method in the base `Object` class which creates a new instance of the correct base class type and copies all the fields (and avoids using any constructors).  So, provided you don't have a custom parent class which does *not* delegate to `Object.clone()` you will always get the current type back.

As a side note, in your example, if `super.clone()` did *not* return an `Employee`, then your code would throw ClassCastException before you even got to the step where you reference `hireDay`.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not delegate to Object.clone()"?